# Combine multiple regression equations

Tags: regression

I want to estimate $Y$ using different independent variables.

$$Y = d_1 +  aX_1\\
Y=  d_2 +  bX_2\\
Y=  d_3 +  cX_3$$

Then I want to combine above 3 equations such that it gives the following relation:

$$Y = d + a_1X_1 + b_1X_2 + c_1X_3$$

How can I use the above 3 regression equations to obtain a single relationship as above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. The separate regression equations contain no information on the correlation between the $X$s, and these are necessary to compute your last regression equation. If you have the raw data you can compute the last equation by using any statistical package and use linear regression and include all three variables.